# Unable to use any of the training optimizers other than tf.train.GradientDescentOptimiser()

Tags: tensorflow

Function() to define Model

```
with tf.variable_scope('RNNLM') as scope:
  self.initial_state = tf.zeros(shape = (self.config.batch_size, self.config.hidden_size) )
  H  = tf.get_variable('H',(self.config.hidden_size, self.config.hidden_size),tf.float32,init)
  I  = tf.get_variable('I',(self.config.embed_size, self.config.hidden_size),tf.float32,init)
  b_1= tf.get_variable('bias-1',(1,self.config.hidden_size),tf.float32,init)
  U  = tf.get_variable('U',(self.config.hidden_size, len(self.vocab)),tf.float32,init)
  b_2= tf.get_variable('bias-2',(1,len(self.vocab)),tf.float32,init)

with tf.variable_scope('RNNLM') as scope:
  scope.reuse_variables()
  self.current_state = self.initial_state
  H  = tf.get_variable('H',(self.config.hidden_size, self.config.hidden_size),tf.float32,init)
  I  = tf.get_variable('I',(self.config.embed_size, self.config.hidden_size),tf.float32,init)
  b_1= tf.get_variable('bias-1',(1,self.config.hidden_size),tf.float32,init)
  U  = tf.get_variable('U',(self.config.hidden_size, len(self.vocab)),tf.float32,init)
  b_2= tf.get_variable('bias-2',(1,len(self.vocab)),tf.float32,init)
  for t in xrange(self.config.num_steps):
    self.current_state = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(self.current_state,H)+tf.matmul(inputs[t],I)+b_1)
    rnn_outputs.append(self.current_state)
  self.final_state = rnn_outputs[-1]
```

function( loss ) to define the training operation

```
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.config.lr).minimize(loss)
```

ValueError: Variable RNNLM/RNNLM/RNNLM/Variable_1/Adadelta/ does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have accidentally put the declare of `train_op` into the scope `RNNLM` which is in 'variable share' mode by calling `scope.reuse_variables()`. Move it out of the scope, and you will get your code run.